# Ruby -- How to require user input while simultaneously showing a countdown

Tags: ruby

(Warning: I'm relatively new to Ruby.)

I'm writing a simple math script that will help my kids learn their addition facts. I want to show a countdown that they need to beat with their answers. So, for instance, while they're watching a countdown go from 5 to 0, they need to press '6 + enter' in order to correctly answer 3 + 3 = ?. The '6 + enter' should stop the countdown and advance them to the next question.

Currently, this is the code for my countdown:

> ```
> 5.downto(0) do |i|
>   print "\r00:00:#{'%02d' % i}"
>   sleep 1
> end
> ```

This works, as far as it goes. It gives me the countdown that I want. The problem is that I need to solicit an answer from the user that will interrupt this countdown -- while the countdown process is still running. As it stands, I could put a

> answer = gets.chomp

after the countdown, but that's obviously not going to help me very much.

Any ideas? I've tried to read up on how to run simultaneous processes, but the explanations have been a bit difficult to follow, and none of the ones that I read about seemed to allow the kind of user interaction I'm after.

Thanks in advance for your help.!

Comment: Take a look at the ``Thread`` library.

Comment: To do two things at once you either have to use two threads or have an event loop running with timers in it, like [EventMachine](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/eventmachine/frames) or [Curses](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html).

Answer (score 1):

Threading is the answer. Here's what I did. It isn't perfect, but it gets the job done.

```
student_answer = nil

timer = Thread.new do
  5.downto(0) do |i|
    puts "\r00:00:#{'%02d' % i}"
    sleep 1
  end
  puts 'Time is up'
end

answer = Thread.new do
  puts 'What is your answer?'
  student_answer = gets.chomp
end 

answer.join(5)
timer.join

if $answer.nil?
  puts 'No Answer'
else
  puts "Your answer is #{student_answer }"
end
```

This code will produce the following output

```
What is your answer?

00:00:05

00:00:04

00:00:03

00:00:02

00:00:01

00:00:00
Time is up
No Answer
```

Of course, you can enter your answer at anytime, but the answer thread is killed about 5 seconds, and you can no longer enter any answer.

Unfortunately, I can not figure out how to kill the timer thread once an answer is inputted. If anyone have any ideas, please let me know.

Comment: Your typing while trying to answer will be pushed around by the timer itself, but hey, this *technically* works.

Comment: is there a way to stop the timer thread based on the value of `$answer`? I couldn't find anything on it.

Comment: Another important note: Don't recommend people use global variables like `$answer`.

Comment: to stop the countdown, you can `break if student_answer` inside `5.downto(0)` loop. (You will also have to deal with not displaying "Time is up".) Or you can directly stop the thread with `Thread.exit`. It is cleaner to have the thread suicide than trying to kill it from outside.